# Binding .htaccess (mod_rewrite)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have search for this issue on Stacks but can't find the solution, so maybe can someone have an solution on the issue below.

I have build an (php)system on a subdomain, now i need to drop it on the server side of the customer, when i've done this, the bindings paths doesnt work anymore.

I see the page but he doesnt load the informatie.

.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^*******\.******\.nl/mtsadmin$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^admin/users/edit/([0-9]+) admin/users.php?edit=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^/formulier /form.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

I have tried it with / before 'admin' and without a '^', but that's not the solution.

Below my page script.

```
if(isset($_GET['edit'])) {
if(trim($_GET['edit']) != '') {
$edit = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id');
$editvar = trim($_GET['edit']);
$edit->bindParam(':id', $editvar, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

The path of the .htaccess
public_html/subdomain/.htaccess

There is a map form and that works.

But in the map 
public_html/subdomain/admin/users.php

This path doesnt work in .htaccess. It works on my own server but doesnt work on the server of my client.

I like to hear from you!

Comment: How are you accessing the PHP file? http://subdomain.yourdomain.com/admin/users.php OR http://yourdomain.com/subdomain/admin/users.php?

Comment: @sariDon subdomain.yourdomain.com/admin/users.php In live http://subdomain.*******.nl/mtsadmin/admin/users/edit/1

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^admin/users/edit/([0-9]+) admin/users.php?edit=$1 [NC]
```

Using ^ mark in rule says that it is very beginning of string to be rewrited.
As you've posted in comments. /admin/users.php WILL be redirected, because it is starting from admin/users as in rule. But /mtsadmin/admin/users does not start with "admin" but rather "mtsadmin" string, and it is not caught by rewrite rule.

Change the mentioned line, to reflect correct path on production server.

Comment: Okay, but why does it work on my server and not on the server of my client. I've the redirect of admin/users.php?edit=1 change to admin/users/edit/1 What works fine is /form.php and /formulier what did i wrong ?

Comment: Probably on your client /form.php and /formulier have the same directories as on your server.
mtsadmin path on your client server is different from admin path on your server and in .htaccess file

Comment: The page load and show no 404 eror, but when i do users.php?edit=1 it works but when i do /users/edit/1 i doesnt work. So is the problem in php script or in .htaccess.